# Code Activity not showing in Toolbox?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, workflow-foundation-4

I've created a new SharePoint project in Visual Studio and added a workflow to it. Then, I added a "Code Activity".

[image]

This generates a class that extends from CodeActivity:

```
public sealed class GetDepartmentManager : CodeActivity
```

However, it does not generate any XML (or Actions4) file. Additionally, after building everything, it is not visible in the toolbar:
[image]

Any ideas/tips/experience on what the problem may be?

Notes: I'm using Workflow Foundation with SharePoint 2013, Visual Studio 2012 and Workflow Manager 1.0.

Comment: They don't magically create designers for your activities.  You have to do this yourself.  As for it not showing in the toolbar, that happens sometimes; you can always add it manually.  Other than that there isn't really a question here :/

Comment: @Will "How to create a custom code activity" is a common question on Google (it turns up in autosuggest) but there are no good, step by step answers. I did not ask for a "magical designer for my activities". Rather, I'm trying to understand why is it that when I add a "Custom Activity", it shows up in the toolbar and in SPDesigner, but with a "Custom code activity" this is not the case. I think I may be missing some steps. Do you know of any good tutorial regarding custom code activities?

Comment: "How to create a custom code activity" isn't a truly answerable question.  It's like asking "how do I create a program to accomplish my goal?"  The answer is "you code it", which isn't exactly helpful.  Now as to why Code Activities don't show up, that's a better question, one I unfortunately don't know the answer to.  Sometimes the toolbox works as expected, sometimes it doesn't.  And your best tutorials are found by using a major search engine.  I'd recommend any results with an msdn blog URL.

Comment: @Will Even if somebody asks "How do I create a program to accomplish my goal", I can point them to open visual studio, create a new project, and tell them where they can write their code. With custom code activities, I don't even know how to do that - because once I've written the code I have no clue how to run it, most probably due to the fact I'm missing some steps - either in development or deployment. Anyway, It's pointless arguing here, especially after reading your last two sentences. It's clear as crystal that you don't want to help.

Comment: I can't really help.  [You can check my activity in this tag to see how I help people who ask practical questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:1228+[workflow-foundation-4]).  The problem you have is that you aren't really at the point where you have one.  You need to do more research, create some basic prototypes (from which answerable questions will emerge!)... take baby steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found this technet blog that describes the steps that need to be taken to deploy a code activity in a Visual Studio 2012, SharePoint 2013 Workflow: http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepointdevelopersupport/archive/2013/08/28/how-to-develop-a-workflow-code-activity-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx